# What happens to the bounty I added to a questions if no new answers are provided before the bounty expires?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty, unanswered-questions

I added a bounty to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35862/very-simple-dice-game) on June 6th. Today I received a warning that my bounty was expiring and that I should attribute it to one or two answers. However, the only answer to the question is the same (unsatisfactory) one that was there when I added the bounty. What will happen to my bounty when it expires if there are no new answers posted during the bounty period?

Comment: I also wanted to see that question answered.  I'm currently offering a bounty for a different question, but as soon as that expires, I'll offer another bounty on "Very simple dice game".

Comment: Thanks @Elliott! That would be great as my measly bounty points weren't enough of an incentive.

Comment: Sorry about the delay; I wanted to wait a while before offering another bounty.  Are you still interested in this question?

Comment: A b s o l u t e l y!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The points will just vanish: No-one gets the points, and you also don't get them back.

Comment: For details see [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)